# Generating md5 for a blinking cursor with perl

Tags: perl, md5sum

I am trying the get the md5sum of a Base64 string using perl.Below is the sample code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict; 
use warnings; 
use Digest::MD5;
my $md5 =  Digest::MD5->new();
my $base64_encoded_string = "base64_encoded_string";
my $md5_add =  $md5->add($base64_encoded_string);
my $md5_add_hex = $md5->hexdigest;
```

The problem is the $base64_encoded_string is for a image of a machine console with blinking cursor , so the $md5_add_hex has two values. one when  cursor is present in the image and other when its missing.

Need advice how can i get the unique md5 value , without cursor in the final $md5_add_hex.

Comment: Base64 and Base54 are different, which did you mean? It doesn't really matter though, two different strings will have two different md5sums and there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Figure out a way to normalize the data to a consistent form before hashing it.

Comment: For example, instruct the console to hide the cursor. It's not like you need it in an automated test suite. But you could also just overwrite the pixels of the image file where the cursor is expected to be

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is the $base64_encoded_string is for a image of a machine console with blinking cursor , so the $md5_add_hex has two values. one when cursor is present in the image and other when its missing.

I'm not really sure that I understand what you mean but the only explanation I have so far is that the image you are talking about is some animated GIF or PNG with a blinking cursor. Your assumption is then that there will be two different MD5 depending on when you run your program - because it sometimes with the cursor and sometimes without.

Only, it does not work this way. An animated GIF or PNG is just data consisting of a series of images together with instructions on how fast to switch between the images. It does not have any inherent state which would change over time. And, MD5 has no idea of images at all. It only takes the data, no matter if these data might be interpreted as a series of images, as a video, as some text document or whatever.